# PHP variables in classes

Tags: php, oop, variables

I have the following code (I'm a Dot Net developers and I thought if I can bring my OOP knowledge to PHP)

```
class user {
    var $_un;
    function user($un) {
     $_un = $un;
    }
    function adduser() {
    }
    function checkuser() {
    }
    function printuser () {
        echo $_un;
    }
}

$newuser = new user('Omar Abid');
$newuser->printuser();
```

So the problem is simple "$_un" is empty!! I want it to be filled, when the class is created using the constructor and then saved.

I used to do that in C# .net, but here it doesn't work for some reasons.
Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In order to access class members in PHP you need to use [`$this->`](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php) .

So what you're currently doing is declaring a local variable called `$_un`, rather than assigned to the member variable `$this->_un` .

Try changing your code to:

```
function user($un) {
 $this->_un = $un;
}

function printuser () {
    echo $this->_un;
}
```

And it should work.

Comment: the other function should changes also

 function printuser () {
  echo $this->_un;
 }

Thanks it's working correctly now

Answer (score 10):

Rather than user() you should use __construct(), it's the preferred way to add a Constructor in PHP5.
Also consider to add visibility to your methods and members (public / protected / private)

```
public function __construct($un) {
    $this->_un = $un;
}
```

Comment: If you have 20 variables for example, would you have to list them as arguments in the __construct(var1, var2, etc) ?

Answer (score 3):

in php you have to use `$this` to access variables (or methods) of the current class, this is necessary to distinguish class members from local variables

Answer (score 2):

Use **this** construct.

```
class user {    
  var $_un;    
  function user($un) 
   {
      $this->_un = $un;    
    }
 }
```