# Properties not being defined by constructor

Tags: php, oop

I've been trying to self-teach some OOP lately, and I came across something which seems curiously strange to me. I was wondering if someone can explain this to me.

I was inspired by one of the questions on this site to try out this little test piece of code (in PHP):

```
class test1 {
    function foo ($x = 2, $y = 3) {
    return new test2($x, $y);
    }
}

class test2 {
    public $foo;
    public $bar;
    function __construct ($x, $y) {
        $foo = $x;
        $bar = $y;
    }
    function bar () {
        echo $foo, $bar;
    }
}

$test1 = new test1;
$test2 = $test1->foo('4', '16');
var_dump($test2);
$test2->bar();
```

Simple stuff. `$test1` should return back an object to `$test2`, with `$test2->foo` equal to 4 and `$test2->bar` equal to 16. My problem with this is that, while `$test2` is being made into an object of class `test2`, both `$foo` and `$bar` within `$test2` are `NULL`. The constructor function is definitely being run - if I echo `$foo` and `$bar` in the constructor function, they show up (with the right values, no less). Yet, despite them being assigned values by `$test1->foo`, they don't show up either through the `var_dump` or through `$test2->bar`. Can someone explain this bit of intellectual curiosity to me?

Comment: $this->foo = $x; $this->bar = $y; in the constructor; and     function bar () { 
        echo $this->foo, $this->bar; 
    } otherwise $foo and $bar are simply local scope variables

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP variables in classes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1292939/php-variables-in-classes)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your syntax is wrong, it should be:

```
class test2 {
    public $foo;
    public $bar;
    function __construct ($x, $y) {
        $this->foo = $x;
        $this->bar = $y;
    }
    function bar () {
        echo $this->foo, $this->bar;
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, that was careless of me. Thanks!

Comment: @Palladium: jeroen got it right. Don't forget to accept his answer.

Answer (score 2):

You should access you class members with 'this':

```
function __construct ($x, $y) {
    $this->foo = $x;
    $this->bar = $y;
}
```